# pass the value of datetimepicker to codebehind (c#)

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, code-behind, datetimepicker

i want to pass the value of a datetimepicker to my Codebehind(C#) and save it to a variable in C#.

I tried it with a hiddenfield but it don't works.

here is the js code:

```
var dates = $("#ArrivalStartDatepicker").datetimepicker({
                            defaultDate: "+lw",
                            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                            changeMonth: true,
                            numberOfMonths: 2,
                            ampm: true,
                            stepMinute: 10,
                            minuteGrid: 10,
                            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                                    document.getElementById("ArrivalStart").value = dates.datetimepicker('getDate');
                                }
                            });
```

the hiddenfield:

```
<div>
          <input type="hidden" id="ArrivalStart" runat="server"/> 
</div>
```

when I choose a date or a time firebug throws the following error:

document.getElementById("ArrivalStart") is null

this tells me that the ArrivalStart-Field isn't accesible in JS.

how can i manage this?

greetz

Tobi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
 document.getElementById("ArrivalStart")
```

use

```
  document.getElementById("<%= ArrivalStart.ClientId %>")
```

That way you inject the ID that ASP.Net created.

**EDIT**
This javascript fragment needs to be in the aspx file (not a separate js file), as ASP.Net needs to process that `<%= .. %>` block and needs access to the ArrivalStart member.

Comment: This is correct. You could also consider using a `<asp:HiddenField>` which allows you to set the `id` using `ClientIdMode="Static"`. This means that you can still use `document.getElementById("ArrivalStart")` as .net will not change the id

Comment: if i use this: document.getElementById("<%= ArrivalStart.ClientId %>")
i get this error: document.getElementById("<%= ArrivalStart.ClientId %>") is null

Comment: is the javascript in the same .aspx file or a separate file?

Comment: that's the problem. I copied the whole code from the seperate file to the  aspx site and it works. what have to be in the aspx site? because i don't want all of the code in this  aspx?

Comment: @user1414157 - this `<%= %>` part needs to be processed by ASP.Net (see edit). For another solution (where you can use a separate js file), see the first comment by Tim B James.

Comment: Yeah if you are using an external js file, then I would create your control as `<asp:HiddenField id="ArrivalStart" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" />` This allows you to access the id.

Comment: i got another question. how could i make a datetime in c# with the value i got from the datetimepicker? this is the value: Thu May 31 2012 06:30:00 GMT+0200 but i just want the date and the time without timezone and dayname, just numbers

Comment: @user1414157 - what is the value of that 'selectedDate' argument? That might solve both your problems!

Comment: the value i see in firebug is: Thu May 31 2012 06:30:00 GMT+0200 but i just want it like this: 5 31 2012 06:30 or 31 5 2012 06:30

Comment: ok i got it. i don't used the 'selectedDate'-value :-) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a control runat=server, c# takes responsibility of rendering the element. Therefore most of the time it will re-write the ID of the control as it needs to take into account what form the control is in and also if it's nested within a data repeater or some other repeating control.

If you run the page and click 'view source' does the ID of the element still equal 'ArrivalStart' or has the ID been rewritten?

If it doesn't you can use C# to write the ClientID of the control (Control.ClientID) into your jQuery script

I could be barking up the wrong tree though :)

Comment: could you give me an exmaple. how can i realize that?